# Unstupidify this query using joins

Tags: sql, join

I have this query that works:

```
select name, location_id from all_names
where location_id in (1,2,3)
and name in(select name from my_names) 
and (name, location_id) not in (select name,location_id from my_names);
```

The purpose of this query is to find all name,location_id tuples in all_names that are not in my_names, as long as those names ARE in my_names.

Being relatively amateur to sql I tried to do some research to fix up this query, but it doesn't quite work. Basically, I tried to use an outer join (name, location_id) tuples from my_name and all_names and identify those rows that returns nulls because those would be rows that didn't have a match.

```
select data.name, data.location_id
from
(select all.name, all.location_id, my.name, my.location_id l_id
from (select name, location_id
from all_names
where location_id in (1,2,3)
)all,
(select name, location_id
from my_names
)my
where all.name = my.name(+)
and all.location_id = my.location_id(+)) data
where data.l_id is null
and data.name is null;
```

This works whenever I add "where data.name='SomeSpecificName'", but when I just run it without that it returns waaay too many rows. Can you help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The first query looks semantically correct. What is the problem with it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Many don't support using multiple lookups for IN().

Comment: *not in my_names, as long as those names ARE in my_names* - seems to be conflicting requirement here :)

Comment: usr: There is no problem with it, but it's slow, isn't it? This query returns a lot of rows, I need it to be fast. PinnyM: What's a DMBS? I'm using Oracle SQL. RedFilter: Haha, the (name,location_id) tuple isn't in my_names, but the name is in my_names.

Comment: @jeremy: Do you have a `(location_id, name)` or a `(name, location_id)` index on `all_names` and `my_names` tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your current query is just fine.

`IN` and `NOT IN` are more efficient than you think. Do a query plan on this and compare to RedFilter's answer.

Comment: It seems bad because I am querying the same table for roughly the same information.

Comment: But, as you can see, RedFilter queries the same table twice as well. Maybe there is a better way, but I can't currently think of it. I would prefer your query over RedFilter's

Comment: As it turns out, mine ran about 30 seconds faster (out of 550 seconds.) I'm surprised, but it looks like you were right!

Comment: Just FYI, using benchmarks is typically not a good way to compare because it's hard to get isolated metrics. You should do a query plan and be able to objectively decide which one does less work. Either way, I think it's safe to conclude that it's not really worth making a change.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name, a.location_id 
from all_names a
inner join my_names m on a.name = m.name
left outer join my_names m2 on a.name = m2.name and a.location_id = m2.location_id
where a.location_id in (1,2,3)
    and m2.name is null
```

Comment: Strangely, this query returns 313k rows and mine returns 309k rows, so I guess they're slightly different, but I'm not sure how!

Comment: Because his does a left outer join on location_id. This means you only have about 4k entries where my_names has 2+ location_id's entered. Each of those would have a duplicate row.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
SELECT
    name,
    location_id
FROM
    all_names a
WHERE
    location_id IN (1,2,3) AND
    name IN (SELECT * FROM my_names) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM my_names m 
                WHERE m.location_id=a.location_id AND m.name=a.name)
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot that location_id has to match too. I corrected it.

Comment: Still wrong. The name also has to have at least one entry in my_names.

Comment: Did you see the `AND m.name=a.name` part?

Comment: Err.. Think this through Olivier. If all_names has a name called 'Olivier' and my_names doesn't have the name 'Olivier', What's stopping it from showing up in the results?

Comment: I think I got it now. I should read the questions more carefully :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the query plan looks like, but you could try:

```
select a.name, a.location_id
from all_names a, my_names m
where a.location_id in (1,2,3)
and a.name = m.name
minus
select name, location_id
from my_names
```

It's a pretty clear way to express your intent, and a chance to use the often-forgotten `minus` operator.